# Best way to create several complex resources of the same type with terraform variables

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I am converting existing kubernetes infrastructure to terraform. I ran a terraform import on the kubernetes cluster that I wanted to convert to terraform. Now that I have the infrastructure terraform code I'm trying to make it reusable. My organization has several clusters and they all have different node pools. I'm working on creating the variables.tf file and I am unsure of the best method to do this. I want to make it so any number of node_pools with specific variables can be created. Ideally I don't want to have to utilize different files/ variables for each node pool i create. Is there a way to place 6  different node_pools into variables without creating inidividual variables for each node pool and resource for the node pool?
For simpler objects I could see count being a viable solution but this might be too complicated. Below are 2 of the 6 node pools I am working with.

````
node_pool {
        initial_node_count          = 12
        # instance_group_urls         = []
        max_pods_per_node           = 16
        name                        = "test-pool"
        node_count                  = 12
        node_locations              = [
            "us-central1-b",
            "us-central1-c",
            "us-central1-f",
        ]
        version                     = "1.21.14-gke.700"

        management {
            auto_repair  = true
            auto_upgrade = true
        }

        node_config {
            disk_size_gb      = 50
            disk_type         = "pd-standard"
            guest_accelerator = []
            image_type        = "COS_CONTAINERD"
            labels            = {
                "integrationtestnode" = "true"
            }
            local_ssd_count   = 0
            machine_type      = "n1-standard-2"
            metadata          = {
                "disable-legacy-endpoints" = "true"
            }
            oauth_scopes      = [
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
            ]
            preemptible       = false
            service_account   = "svcs-dev@megacorp-dev-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
            spot              = false
            tags              = []
            taint             = [
                {
                    effect = "NO_SCHEDULE"
                    key    = "integrationtest"
                    value  = "true"
                },
            ]

            shielded_instance_config {
                enable_integrity_monitoring = true
                enable_secure_boot          = true
            }
        }

        upgrade_settings {
            max_surge       = 1
            max_unavailable = 0
        }
    }


node_pool {
        initial_node_count          = 1
        max_pods_per_node           = 110
        name                        = "promop-n2s8"
        node_count                  = 1
        node_locations              = [
            "us-central1-b",
            "us-central1-c",
            "us-central1-f",
        ]
        version                     = "1.21.13-gke.900"

        management {
            auto_repair  = true
            auto_upgrade = true
        }

        node_config {
            disk_size_gb      = 100
            disk_type         = "pd-standard"
            guest_accelerator = []
            image_type        = "COS_CONTAINERD"
            labels            = {
                "megacorp.reserved" = "promop-dev"
            }
            local_ssd_count   = 0
            machine_type      = "n2-standard-8"
            metadata          = {
                "disable-legacy-endpoints" = "true"
            }
            oauth_scopes      = [
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
            ]
            preemptible       = false
            service_account   = "svcs-dev@megacorp-dev-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
            spot              = false
            tags              = []
            taint             = [
                {
                    effect = "NO_SCHEDULE"
                    key    = "app"
                    value  = "prometheus-operator-dev"
                },
            ]

            shielded_instance_config {
                enable_integrity_monitoring = true
                enable_secure_boot          = false
            }

            workload_metadata_config {
                mode = "GKE_METADATA"
            }
        }

        upgrade_settings {
            max_surge       = 2
            max_unavailable = 0
        }
    }

...

```
````

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear. What variables? You haven't show any. Why `count` is too difficult? What does it mean?

Comment: Basically I want to have only one node_pool {} in my main.tf and use variables to specify if I'm using more than one node_pool and to define each different part of node_pool.